# I am combining two tables for a trigger and am getting issues with creating it?

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_enumber
BEFORE INSERT on emp
FOR EACH ROW
Declare result NUMBER;
dnumber NUMBER;
d_name VARCHAR(20);
Begin
check_eno(:new.ENO, result);
IF result = -1 THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20502, 'deptno already exist');
insert into emp_audit(ENO,ENAME,SAL,DNAME) values 
(:new.ENO,:new.ENAME,:new.SAL,:new.DNAME);
END IF;

IF Find_Dn(:new.DNAME) = 1 THEN
Select DNO, DNAME INTO dnumber, d_name
FROM dept
WHERE :new.DNAME = d_name;
:new.dno = dnumber;
IF d_name = 'SALES' THEN
:new.COMM := 300;
Update DEPT Set tot_sals = tot_sals + :new.SAL;
Update DEPT Set tot_emps = tot_emps + 1;  
END IF;
END IF; 
END;
/
```

LINE/COL ERROR

---

16/13    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ; indicator
         The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

19/36    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "_" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( , * @ % & - + ; / at mod remainder rem return returning
         where || multiset
         The symbol ". was inserted before "_" to continue.

----------------------------------New Code and Error Message---------------------------

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_enumber
  2  BEFORE INSERT on emp
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4     Declare result NUMBER;
  5     dnumber NUMBER;
  6     d_name VARCHAR(20);
  7  Begin
  8   check_eno(:new.ENO, result);
  9   IF result = -1 THEN
 10     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20502, 'deptno already exist');
 11     insert into emp_audit(ENO,ENAME,SAL,DNAME) values
 12             (:new.ENO,:new.ENAME,:new.SAL,:new.DNAME);
 13   END IF;
 14
 15   IF Find_Dname(:new.DNAME) = 1 THEN
 16     Select DNO, DNAME INTO dnumber, d_name
 17     FROM dept
 18     WHERE :new.DNAME :=d_name;
 19     :new.dno = dnumber;
 20     IF d_name = 'SALES' THEN
 21     :new.COMM := 300;
 22     Update DEPT Set tot_sals = tot_sals + :new.SAL;
 23     Update DEPT Set tot_emps = tot_emps + 1;
 24     END IF;
 25     END IF;
 26  END;
 27  /
```

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors;
Errors for TRIGGER CHECK_ENUMBER:

LINE/COL ERROR

---

13/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/20    PL/SQL: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name
16/11    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ; indicator
         The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this line `:new.dno = dnumber;` is causing the first issue(colon missing).

It should be changed to `:new.dno := dnumber;`

For second issue(**Thanks `Mr. Glenn`**), please update(remove space in tot _sals) `Update DEPT Set tot_sals = tot _sals + :new.SAL;` to

```
 Update DEPT Set tot_sals = tot_sals + :new.SAL;
```

There seems to be another issue at line `WHERE :new.DNAME :=d_name;`. Please remove the ":" from the statement as:

```
 WHERE :new.DNAME = d_name;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion @Yogendra  it did not solve the issue

Comment: Are you still getting both errors as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: I think @YogendraSingh is right, but there are some more errors, for example `tot _sals` (contains extra space).

Comment: @Glenn : Good catch. I think that is the second issue. I will update the answer.

Comment: @user1748624 Please refer the updated answer to correct the second issue as found by Mr. `Glen`.

Comment: I am still getting this error after the modifications: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; indicator The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Comment: @user1748624 - OK. **I found another error**. Please refer the updated answer.

Comment: Did you update the `WHERE :new.DNAME = d_name;` clause i.e. did you remove the `:` before `=` ? In your updated question, it doesn't seems so(please look at line number 18 of your code).

Comment: I updated the WHERE :new.DNAME = d_name; clause and getting an error

Comment: In yout new code, I still see these two incorrect lines: 
`WHERE :new.DNAME :=d_name;` <- Extra colon
`:new.dno = dnumber;` <--Missing colon